# How to draw a blueprint for a designer for iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, drawing

I want to show my designer something so he ccan build it for my iPhone app.
Is there any website or tool in which I can easilie draw something with iPhone patterns or something and show him what I want to have?

Comment: ya there is a tool for it ., "MockUp"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

some easy and free tool I have been using in the past: http://mokk.me/

But beware - it's still in beta, but compared to other tools which require either Adobe AIR ( http://www.balsamiq.com/ ) or are bound to a single platform (Mac, Win) and somewhat expensive this is a really good way to draw mockups for an iPhone App.

Answer (score 2):

These are some of the tools for iOS. But most of them are at a cost. you can try whichever is convenient for you.

http://www.omnigroup.com/products/omnigraffle/

http://graffletopia.com/

http://www.teehanlax.com/blog/iphone-gui-psd-v4/

http://balsamiq.com/download

http://keynotopia.com/

https://gomockingbird.com/

Answer (score 1):

Another approach would be to use the "Storyboard" feature within newer versions of Xcode.  Even though it's designed to produce actual interfaces for programs, it also works well as a high-level design tool for describing a sequence of screens and how they relate to each other.

In my current project, I'm not using a storyboard for the actual UI (because I need a little more control over view logic than it allows) but I do use it to sketch out how the visual portions of the application should appear and how they should interact with each other.